# Scraping a Dynamic Page Using Mechanize and Ruby

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to load the following page through mechanize:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B014R6MVH2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014R6MVH2)

The Product Description div (div id="productDescription) seems to be a javascript driven section, and as such, is unavailable to mechanize.

Is there any solution to this? Maybe a gem I could use to execute the javascript and see the section?

Another option could be to use a headless browser. I've tried selenium, but it's much, much slower than mechanize.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.This is covered many times on Stack Overflow, and on the internet. Where have you looked, what have you tried, and why didn't those pages help? If you do some searching you'll find the solutions to your question.

Comment: Hello. I've looked all over both Stack Overflow and the internet before posting this question. The best solution I found on here previously, was to use Execjs (a Ruby Gem) with mechanize to extract javascript, but without any explanation on how to do so. Others recommended headless browsers, but Selenium (for example) is very resource heavy, and can't compare to mechanize in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B014R6MVH2'
page.at('#productDescription .content').text
#=> Description  This item is a simple and useful wedding banner....
```

Comment: Thanks - works ok with the default mechanize user agent, but stops working when a custom user agent is used